# arping equivalent for IPv6

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, arp

What is an equivalent for IPv6 of
`arping -q -c 3 -A -I [device] [ip]`?

I know, there is not an arp in IPv6 and Neighbor solicitation used instead, but which linux user space tool can send such solicitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try rdisc6 . you can download it from: http://www.remlab.net/ndisc6/

Comment: unfortunately, it can't be used in my case

Answer (score 2):

Just enable **DAD**

I'm presuming that you are using this command to force the default gateway to update if you are doing a failover by moving an IPv6 address between machines.

(if not the case, let me know and I'll delete this answer)

My colo provider has Cisco routers and failover is not instant.

The best I had was to use:

```
ping6 -c3 -I 2001:db8:2:d2::38 ff02::2%eth0:3
```

ff02::2 means all routers.

But then I realised that **enabling DAD** works.  It is mean to detect if you have duplicate IP addresses on the network.  But a neat side effect us getting the Cisco to update it's neighbour discovery tables.  I can now move IPv6 addressses between machines almost instantly.