# How does arp works in IPV6?

Tags: ipv6, arp

In my project, I have a scenario of replace node with IPv6 environment

When I assign one IPv6 address to node1 lets say xyz IP.
By some reason if node1 goes offline, I will need to bring all services which were there on node1 to other node, lets say node2 for high availability.

For this I try to assign same IPv6 ip xyz to node2 but it is not working.
because ping to IPv6 gateway is not working from node2.
Possible reason could be gateway has stale information of mac (might be pointing to old node node1) and hence it don’t work.

How can I flush entries of old MAC entry and xyz IP from gateway by triggering any commands from node2? In my case I will not have direct access to gateway/router to do same. will need to do it from node2 only.

Had read about ARP in IPv4, do we have something like ARP which can help me here in IPv6 scenario.
Please suggest me any commands if there.
Have already tried, 'neigh flush all' command it didn't work for me.

Comment: You should be more precise about your environment : gateway/router model, node model. There are no generic answers for such a question excepted « you should use anycast addresses » which would not help you.

Comment: The ~equivalent of ARP in IPv6 is the neighbor discovery protocol, NDP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol

Comment: See also this Q/A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36042/arping-equivalent-for-ipv6